# What is the best way to show the number of users in a table?

Tags: tables, information, team, management, avatars

In your opinion, what is the most clear and fastest way to see the number of members that belong to a specific team?

1- Just having the number

2- Having avatars, where you can mouse hover to see the name of the member

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. Why do users need to see all members at once, what is the amount of members (min, max, average) etc. A table like this can’t have the intention to make it easy to see all members, so without any more details it should be option 1.

Answer (score 1):

As with most design questions, there isn't necessarily an answer that fits all requirements. Usually it depends on how you want to use the information presented, and there might be a primary usage and any number of secondary use cases.

For example, the clearest and fastest way to see the number of people in a team when you are only looking at one row at a time would be to display the actual numerical value. But the fastest way to see the team with the highest number of people for all the teams in a table would probably be to represent the number of people as a bar to allow a faster visual comparison. Of course, if you can sort the table that would be even faster.

So there isn't a single answer, but there are multiple strategies depending on how the information is going to be used.